# Unit testing of SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHTTPRequest> in netty

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, netty

I am new to netty framework.We have a API Handler implementing SimpleChannelInboundHandler and overriding the ChannelRead0 function that takes ChannelHandlerContext and the FullHTTPRequest.Now I need to do unit testing mocking the inputs.
Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume I want to test my `MyContentExtractionHandler`, which looks like this:

```
public class MyContentExtractionHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        int contentLenght = msg.content().capacity();
        byte[] content = new byte[contentLenght];
        msg.content().getBytes(0, content);
        ctx.fireChannelRead(new String(content));
    }
}
```

I will create a regular `DefaultFullHttpRequest` and use mockito to mock a `ChannelHandlerContext`. My unit test would look like this:

```
public class MyContentExtractionHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    ChannelHandlerContext mockCtx = BDDMockito.mock(ChannelHandlerContext.class);

    MyContentExtractionHandler myContentExtractorHandler = new MyContentExtractionHandler();

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        String content = "MyContentHello";
        DefaultFullHttpRequest fullHttpRequest = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "/my /uri", Unpooled.copiedBuffer(content.getBytes()));
        myContentExtractorHandler.channelRead(mockCtx, fullHttpRequest);
        BDDMockito.verify(mockCtx).fireChannelRead(content); //verify that fireChannelRead was called once with the expected result
    }
}
```

Most possibly, your `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` will be the final handler. So instead of checking for `fireChannelRead()` check for whatever method you call after reading the message.

Comment: what would the MyUrlExtractorHandler do here could you explain.I am very new to netty and mockito.

Comment: Alright, see my update answer. I guess more detailed is not possible...